# Unix set file permission as another file

Tags: unix

Is there any way to make file A has exactly same file permission as file B without specify permission like 777. For example, usually I `ls` file B and check its permission setting. Then 'chmod ??? fileA'. However, I am looking for a command like

`chmod --argument_to_copy_file_permission fileA fileB`

Please advise.

EDIT:
By the way, is there any command to see file permission in digit mode (like 777), thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in Linux; i'm not sure whether the programs or options are POSIX.

```
chmod `stat -c '%a' fileB` fileA
```

On Mac OSX, the following works about the same, but using options that work.  :)

```
chmod `stat -f '%Op' fileB` fileA
```

(That's an uppercase "o", not a zero.)

Again, i don't know whether that's POSIX.  I do know it won't work on Linux; the -f option means something totally different there.

Either way, both commands work by taking the output of the `stat` command on fileB, specifically the octal-formatted file modes, and uses that as the mode to set on fileA.  This means the stuff in between the backquotes will give you the file modes.

Comment: no good on Mac OSX

Comment: @ennuikiller: Edited.

Answer (score 5):

`chmod --reference=fileA fileB` should do it according to the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Comment: +1, hadn't spotted that before! Appears to be specific to GNU chmod.

Comment: true, it's GNU specific and does not work on BSD or Mac OSX

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty short perl script:

```
my ($dev, $ino, $mode, @junk) = stat "fileA";
$mode &= 07777;  # mode includes type information in higher bits
printf "%o\n", $mode;
chmod $mode, "fileB";
```

Making it take arguments and options left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 1):

#### Sort Of

```
$ chmod ugo=rwxrwxrwx filename
```

This way you can just type in what `ls(1)` reports, or write a simple script to do it.

This will work on all versions of Unix including Linux and the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I little longer than the perl script:

```
chmod $(ls -l file.whose.permissions.you.want.to.copy | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}' | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s also a pretty short Python script:

```
import os
os.chmod('fileA', os.stat('fileB').st_mode)
```

And Ruby:

```
File.chmod(File.stat('fileA').mode, 'fileB')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output of `stat`, modify it, and then use that to change the permissions of `fileB`:

```
stat fileA | grep "Access: (" | cut -c 10-13 | xargs -i  chmod {} fileB
```